# How to run a python3 script with pm2

Tags: python-3.x, pm2

Pm2 default start command runs a script using python2. How can I make it run a script using python3 ? Let us say my script is called app.py .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
pm2 start app.py --interpreter python3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run your python script with pm2 in many ways.

- **Method 1: Run the script with default python interpreter**

  If you are trying to run the script using the default python interpreter installed in your machine then use the following command,

  ```
  pm2 start app.py --interpreter python3
  ```
- **Method 2: Run the script with interpreter installed in the virtual environment**

  If you have a virtual environment configured for the script then use the following commmand,

  ```
  pm2 start app.py --interpreter venv/bin/python3
  ```
- **Method 3: Specify the app name**

  You can specify the app name because pm2 gives the app name as the script name by default,

  ```
  pm2 start app.py --interpreter venv/bin/python3 --name genxword
  ```